# How to punctuate a list of names in a family

Tags: punctuation

How do I say:
We welcome our new pastor James Quinn; his wife, Deana and their children John, Patti, and Chris.
Is that the correct way to punctuate?

Comment: Comma after "Deana" maybe

Comment: If you're going to use a semicolon (after _Quinn_) as a super-comma, be consistent and use one after _Deana_ too.

Comment: *James Quinn, his wife, Deana* Is the list at two or three? The roles and those who play them are so closely associated that you don't really need the commas to signal the appositives: *pastor James Quinn, his wife Deanna, and their children John, Patti, and Chris. But punctuation is a matter of style. Suit yourself.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma#Uses_in_English), In general, the comma shows that the words immediately before the comma are less closely or exclusively linked grammatically to those immediately after the comma than they might be otherwise. So you could just replace ';' with ',' and it would makes sense more and will be more consistent.

Answer (score 1):

We welcome our new pastor James Quinn, his wife Deana, and their children John, Patti, and Chris.

You only need a semi colon if the list is more complicated

You can find an example here: 
http://www.grammar-monster.com/lessons/semicolons_in_lists.htm